# Find data cell value, move up one cell in column, find next data cell within a column and get next value

Tags: excel, vba

With the code below I'm trying to do the following:

- Find file that matches the first IF statement
- In wbkOut, go to the 2nd column and find the first cell with data (bottom, up) and also    assign that a value, so we can reference it later as the place to start the do loop
- In wbkVer, find the first cell with data, offset down 1 cell, resize the data from wbkout for only 1 cell
- The value of the wbkOut cell is then added to the wbkVer cell
- All of the above works
- What doesn't work is the next piece
- If the script has run, then offset the cell to paste in by one.. and also offset the the wbkOut cell up one cell and start looking for the next cell with data, etc...
- Do until tenln no longer has a value

I can't get the loop to work properly, suggestions?  Thanks!

Edit: I can get the first 2 values and then the loop runs indefinitely not finding anything else.

```
Dim strOutputFile As Variant
Dim wbkOut As Workbook
Dim tenln As Range
Dim tenlnPaste As Range
Dim hasRun As Boolean
Dim wbkVer As Workbook

    If strOutputFile(u) Like "*Lines.csv" Then
        With wbkOut.Worksheets(1)
        Set tenln = wbkOut.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)
        Set tenlnPaste = wbkVer.Worksheets("TLines").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(tenln.Rows.Count, 1)
            tenlnPaste.Value = tenln.Value
        hasRun = True
        Do
            If hasRun = True Then
            With wbkOut.Worksheets(1)
                tenlnPaste.Offset(1, 0).Value = tenln.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlUp).Value
            End With
            End If
        Loop Until tenln.value = ""
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? Because in 2003 there's only this much cells you can keep adding and it is limited ;)

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010! :)

Comment: If I read this correctly tenln is a range object?

Comment: ack sorry, yes.  let me put the variables in there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the do loop of what you have written is that you are not modifying `tenln` so whatever value you set at the beginning will stay the same and `tenln = ""` will always be false

If I read this correctly `tenln` s a range object so you can use a for loop instead.

```
For each c in tenln.cells

  'your code here
  If c.value = "" then exit for
Next
```

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting the same result.  It does the first two and then ends.  It's not dynamically linking from the previous cell during the loop.

Comment: I was able to figure this out and do it another way.  I'll post the code in a few minutes.